# Arrays with 0 elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is an array with 0 elements the same as an unallocated pointer?

Is `int arr[0];` the same as `int* arr;`?

Edit: What if I did something similar to this:

```
int x[0];
int* const arr = x;
```

I tried this code and it compiled. To my knowledge, both x and arr should be pointing to the same location in memory. What would be the difference in this case?

Comment: A pointer can always point to something new, whereas an array is statically defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not at all.

In the case of arr[0], **arr** has a well defined address.

In the case of *arr, **arr** is just uninitialized.

*After your EDIT*, where you initialize the **const arr** with an array defined just before : there would just be no difference in the content of the variables, but in the actions you would be allowed to perform on them.

Comment: @Dasaru Did you try it? That doesn’t compile …

Comment: @Dasaru : normally you could ... but you'd have to initialize manually the **arr** to a given memory location, as it is const. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355258/why-must-const-members-be-intialized-in-the-constructor-initializer-rather-than

Comment: In C++ it's not legal to have a zero length array, therefore the array will not have a well defined address.

Comment: @bames53 : thanks for the clarification. Would you have the source of that info ?

Comment: It comes from the C++ standard, [dcl.array] Chapter 8.3.4/1. "If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero." (The standard can be downloaded from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/#mailing2012-01). Look for paper "n3337") There's actually more to it than just that quote, but it can't all be quoted here.

Answer (score 4):

A locally declared zero-length array is illegal in C++ so it's not the same as an unallocated pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A zero-length array points to a specific address, the beginning of the array. After the end of the array, you will have undefined data, in this case, at the address pointed to.

```
int arr[0];
int* ptr;

// arr is a reliable value;
// *arr is not;
// ptr is not;
```

One way this is useful: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: As far as I know there still is no consensus about whether this usage is actually legal according to the standard, since array access outside of bounds is simply UB (and *does* cause bugs in software, this is not merely a hypothetical).

Comment: @KonradRudolph In C90, there was no question: `int arr[0]` was illegal, including in a structure.  And it was clear that if the array was declared `int arr[1];`, and you accessed with and index 2, it was undefined behavior.  C99 (but not C++), you can declare the final member of a struct as `int arr[];` to support this usage (but `int arr[0];` remains an error).

Comment: @James Ah, that was it. So what about C++? I’m pretty sure that out-of-bounds array access was never legal, am I right?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Generally speaking, for the basic types, pointers and C style arrays, the intent of C++ is to be identical to C.  (There is one exotic architecture which C++ formally forbid, but C allowed, at least in C++03.  This was accepted as a defect, and has presumably been fixed in C++11, although I've not verified.)